# How to convert a Bytebeat code to .wav or .mp3

Tags: audio, converters

this is my first post and I hope I will have an answer quickly, I was wondering if someone knows a bit bytebeat coding, because I used an online generator.
I modified the code and it worked on the website (the sound preview).

I don't know how to convert it to .wav or .mp3 and how to improve the code.
ChatGPT told me that I need to improve the code so can anyone help me?
Thank you